# What's wrong with Requirepackage[leqno]{amsthm}?

Tags: amsthm

I try to write my own documentclass, but something goes wrong when I
add an option `[leqno]` for the package `amsthm`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mybook}[2018/05/28 Free LaTeX text book template from Typesetters.se]
\LoadClass[11pt,
               onecolumn,
               titlepage,
               twoside,
               openany
               ]{book}
......
\Requirepackage[leqno]{amsthm}
```

Error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `leqno.thm' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: thm)
```

Comment: oh, thanks. where should I add this option, if I need somthing like 1.1 lemma, 1.2 propostion, 1.3 theorem....

Comment: Do `\swapnumbers` before starting to define theorems.

Answer (score 1):

`leqno` isn't a valid option for `amsthm`. The package handles options through the line

```
\DeclareOption*{\input{\CurrentOption .thm}}
```

So for every `option` passed to `amsthm` the system looks for a file `option.thm`, and `leqno.thm` simply doesn't exist.

I guess you might want to pass `leqno` to `amsmath`, not `amsthm`.

Comment: In fact, I want to have something like 1.1 lemma, 1.2 proposition, 1.3 definition, 1.4 x^2+2x=y, with the numbering on the left of enviroment name.

Comment: You can load  `amsthm` AND `thmtools`. For the latter, what you want is obtained with the key `theoremstyle=swapnumber`. You also may consider loading `ntheorem`,  for which it is `\theoremsty{change}`.